# Vim: When folding code allow tabs to remain

Tags: unix, vim, tabs

In vim I would like to change the folding behavior.  Suppose I fold this block:

```
=== fileName ===

        == summary ==

                I think that this defines the class to use for the authentication
                and the parameters to pass the class.

        == tags ==

                <bla bla>
                </bla bla>
```

It becomes:

```
=== fileName ===

        == summary ==

+---  2 lines: I think that this defines the class to use for the authentication------------

        == tags ==

                <bla bla>
                </bla bla>
```

I think that it would be easier to read if it became:

```
=== fileName ===

        == summary ==

                +---  2 lines: I think that this defines the class to use for the authentication------------

        == tags ==

                <bla bla>
                </bla bla>
```

(The desired result has an extra tab)

FYI: I have this in my vimrc:

```
"use indents as the folding method
set foldmethod=indent

"make vim save and load the folding of the document each time it loads
au BufWinLeave * mkview
au BufWinEnter * silent loadview
```

## Update

Upon recommendation from  [njd](https://superuser.com/questions/112497/vim-when-folding-code-allow-tabs-to-remain/112846#112846)  I tried setting the foldtext to my own function.  I tried both the one that he suggested and the one below.  However neither had any effect.

```
function! MyFoldText()
  return 'johnny'
endfunction

set foldtext=MyFoldText()
```

What am I missing here?

***Note:*** I also have this: `set foldmethod=indent` in my .vimrc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to have the fold message line up with the indent of the folded text?

You need to set the '`foldtext`' option to something other than the default **foldtext()** function.

Something like this:

```
function! MyFoldText()
  let lines = 1 + v:foldend - v:foldstart
  let spaces = repeat(' ', indent(v:foldstart))

  let linestxt = 'lines'
  if lines == 1
    linestxt = 'line'
  endif

  let firstline = getline(v:foldstart)
  let line = firstline[ind : ind+80]

  return spaces . '+' . v:folddashes . ' ' . lines . ' ' . linestxt . ': ' . line . ' '
endfunction
```

Then

```
:set foldtext=MyFoldText()
```

Comment: Wow is there really not an easier answer?

Comment: Easier like ":set foldmessageplacement=indent" ? No. No such option exists.
Just paste that function into your .vimrc, and add the :set command, and you're done. Easy.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback.  Put that code into my .vimrc but it had no effect.  I modified the function to this: 

`function! MyFoldText()
  return 'hello world'
endfunction

set foldtext=MyFoldText()`

But this also had no effect on the folding.  Can you offer some clarification as to why this may be having no effect?

Comment: My mistake - that "return ..." line should have the correct string concatenator (.) before v:folddashes instead of +. I've corrected my answer. You won't see the change until you reopen and then close a fold.

Comment: Hmm, ok looks like there was a conflict with something else in my vimrc.  That fixed it up.  However let i += 1 did not work on my machine I needed to use let i = i+1

Comment: I also found that this line: `let line = firstline[ind : ind+80]` did not work so I changed it for `let line = firstline`